# How does System.Text.Encoding class work?

Tags: .net, character-encoding, mscorlib

In .NET, there is a class called `System.Text.Encoding` in `mscorlib`. But when you do `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII`, you can access the ASCII encoding class.

At first, I thiught this was a class in a class kind of thing:

```
class Encoding {
    class ASCII { ... }
    ...
}
```

But what is confusing is that you can also use `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding` to access the same functions.

Not being able to decompile .NET (as .NET Reflector costs money and I don't understand IL that well [so no ildasm]), I can't wrap my head around how the two classes are equal. Could it be something like this?

```
class ASCIIEncoding {
    internal ASCIIEncoding() { ... }
    /* static functions */
}
static class Encoding {
    public static readonly ASCIIEncoding ASCII = new ASCIIEncoding();
    ...
}
```

This seems like the most likely way, but the function prototype is

```
public static Encoding ASCII { get; }
```

Returning a class deriviated from `Encoding` doesn't make sense as Encoding is a class with the Encoding types (ASCII, UTF-(7/8/16/32), etc.), so that means that `ASCIIEncoding` would need those variables also, no?

Can anyone help clear up this confusion?

Comment: For .NET source code, see here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx

Comment: You're developing software on a mobile device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Returning a class deriviated from Encoding doesn't make sense as Encoding is a class with the Encoding types (ASCII, UTF-(7/8/16/32), etc.), so that means that ASCIIEncoding would need those variables also, no?

No, because `Encoding.ASCII` etc are *static* properties, presumably backed by *static* fields (although that's an implementation detail - the property could just create a new instance each time, or there could be a static internal field within `ASCIIEncoding` which it uses, etc).

It's just like this:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    private readonly static BaseClass firstDerived = new FirstDerived();
    private readonly static BaseClass secondDerived = new SecondDerived();

    public static BaseClass First
    { 
        get { return firstDerived; } 
    }

    public static BaseClass Second
    { 
        get { return secondDerived; } 
    }
}

public class FirstDerived : BaseClass {}
public class SecondDerived : BaseClass {}
```

That's complete code - albeit useless in terms of the derived classes actually *doing* anything. Make sure you understand every bit of how that works, and then just apply it to `Encoding`...